Error: AnchorError caused by account: token_metadata_program. Error Code: InvalidProgramExecutable. Error Number: 3009
I run anchor test and then it shows Error: AnchorError caused by account: token_metadata_program. Error Code: InvalidProgramExecutable. Error Number: 3009. Error Message: Program account is not executable., token_metadata_program I defined in testb file looks like
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct testb<'info> {
    // Use ADMIN_PUBKEY as constraint, only the specified admin can invoke this instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    // The PDA is both the address of the mint account and the mint authority
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"jelly"],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = jelly_token_mint,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    
    ///CHECK: Using "address" constraint to validate metadata account address, this account is created via CPI in the instruction
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&jelly_token_mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub jelly_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}


and here is my test code
it("Is create mint!", async () => {


    const jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: JellyTokenMintPDA });

    const tx = await program.methods
    .test(jellymetadata.uri, jellymetadata.name,  jellymetadata.symbol)
    .accounts({
      jellyTokenMint: JellyTokenMintPDA,
      jellyMetadataAccount: jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });


I fixed by clone metaplex to local , look up https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/accounts-and-data/fork-programs-to-localnet

It would be easier for you to dump token_metadata program and set it to your Anchor's test enviornment.
In terminal:
solana program dump metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s mpl_token_metadata.so
In Anchor.toml file:
[[test.genesis]] address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s" program = "mpl_token_metadata.so"
